# Pulling parameters off a function passed as an argument

Tags: javascript, closures

I am attempting to implement underscore's memoize function.

Memoize should be called as follows:

```
subtract = function(a, b) {
  return a - b;
};

memoSub = _.memoize(subract);
memoSub(2, 1);
//1
```

Memoize should "remember" previous calls to its saved function, and rather than re-calculate (re-run the function), it should return those saved values.

I have the following structure set up, but the difficulty I'm having is understanding how I can access the passed-in function's parameters so that I can somehow save them, and thus check if they're the same as previously passed-in parameters.

Below is essentially an implementation of `_.once`, which I don't need to access the passed-in function's arguments for. I'm trying to modify it to make it into `_.memoize`

```
  _.memoize = function(func) {

    var called = false;
    //i'd rather this be var storedArgs = {};
    var result;

    return function() {
      //i'd rather be checking if these args have been seen before
      if (!called) {
        result = func.apply(this, arguments);
        called = true;
        //i'd rather save the computed results to the storedArg obj here
      }
      return result;
    };
  };
```

`func.apply` allows me to call a function and pass in the master `arguments`, i.e., everything after `func` in my function definition, but how then can I access the parameters/arguments of `func`? (In this case the parameters are `(a, b)` as seen above.

Edit: I suspect what I really need to do is somehow access the non-existent parameters here:

```
return function(/*how can I "capture" what will go here?*/) {...}
```

Comment: `result = func.apply(this, arguments);` is forwarding `arguments` to the function you're wrapping. What else do you need to capture? you already have `arguments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have your answer, the arguments object inside the inner function is exactly what you're trying to capture.

Both the inner and outer functions have an arguments variable but once you're in the inner function the outer variable is shadowed but the inner one.

Comment: So: 

    `_.memoize = function(func){
         //arguments  = arguments for memoize
            return function(){
                //arguments = arguments for returned function
            }
    }`

Like that?

Answer (score 1):

You already have access to the arguments via `arguments`. What you need is a mapping of the arguments to the result. If the map contains an entry for the currently passed arguments, return the result. If not, compute it and store it.

Example:

```
var results = {};
return function() {
  var key = Array.prototype.join.call(arguments);
  if (!(key in results)) {
    return results[key] = func.apply(this, arguments);
  }
  return results[key];
};
```

Note: This does a very simple serialization of the arguments and wouldn't work for complex arguments (objects).